# Editing out obvious spam

Tags: discussion

Earlier today there was an obvious spam answer, I downvoted and marked as spam and it was deleted within a matter of minutes. I can't reference the answer now but it was a basic LED question and the 'answer' was something like "We are LED supplier, please e-mail us at sales@ledsrus.com for requirements".

I noticed CamilStaps edited out the e-mail address which of course was well intentioned but I seem to remember asking W5VO or Kortuk about it in chat several months ago and they mentioned that being the last editor on a spam post can put some sort of flag against your account so it wasn't a good idea.

I've seen a few others with edit ability do the same especially with web links so thought I'd throw the question out here in meta for a more permanent record on the question of whether editing out spam is a good idea before a question or answer is deleted?